# cURL with SSL verification works but how do I validate that it is encrypted?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, encryption, cloudflare

I own 2 websites, `example.com` and `domain.com`. Both DNS's are hosted on Cloudflare. [Cloudflare offers free SSL/TLS encryption on their dashboard.](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/). Both the websites are set to Full encryption mode with forced HTTPS rewrites. `example.com` is hosted on WebHostingA and `domain.com` is hosted on HosterB.

I want to use `domain.com` to get the contents from `example.com/test.php`.

**Code on: `domain.com/get-contents.php`**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['username' => 'Bob']);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

**Code on: `example.com/test.php`**

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && ctype_alpha($_POST['username'])) {

    echo($_POST['username'] . " You got my contents!");

} else {
    echo("Nope!");
}
```

I am able to successfully return get the contents from `example.com/test.php` (`Bob You got my contents!`). However, my concern is that I did not have to provide any sort of certificates in the cURL code. How do I check if what I sent from `domain.com` was encrypted and what I received back from `example.com` was encrypted? My goal is to securely transfer data between these 2 websites.

Comment: The certificate file is defined in php.ini in section `[curl]`

Comment: @ITgoldman Would my 2 web hosting providers (WebHostingA and HosterB) automatically update their certificate file when I enabled the SSL on cloudflare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you used `https` scheme, it means curl connected using tls. `https://example.com/test.php` & `http://example.com/test.php` are different urls and curl doesn't change the scheme by itself.

Second - in some situations there can be a redirect on the server side to plain http. To ensure that there is no redirect and the connection is encrypted, you may try to use `curl_getinfo()` function and check the `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` and `CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT` fields like that:

```
$r = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT);
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

`$r` should be 0, `$url` should start with `https://`.

Also you can use tcpdump on any of this servers to record the request and try to check dump for any plain data.

```
[server1]# tcpdump -l -n -s 0 -w dump.pcap host server2.ip.addres
```

you will see the ports of the connection and record captured data to the dump.pcap file. If one of the ports is 443 - you traffic was sent using tls. Also you can later analyze dump.pcap file in wireshark or just using `strings` command.

Comment: To clarify, what you are saying is that because I am able to get the contents, everything is in fact encrypted? So I am using shared hosting, so not sure if I can do this. Anyway to check on PHP itself?

Comment: Yes, if https scheme is ok - connection was encrypted. In some situations, when you don't control the scripts at both sides - there can be a redirect on the server side to plain http but it is not your case. To ensure that, you may try to use curl_getinfo() function and check the CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL and CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT fields.


I believe that you cannot run tcpdump on a shared hosting.

Comment: So to use it those functions I simply do `var_dump(curl_getinfo(CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT));` after `curl_exec()`? Because when I do that I get `NULL`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php:
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT)

Comment: `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` gave me the result: `https://example.com/test.php`
`CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT` gave me the result `0`

Comment: It means everything is ok. scheme is https, as for verifyresult - https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT.html

Comment: I tried the same thing on my localhost (my localhost does not have any HTTPS). I was still able to obtain `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` as: `https://example.com/test.php` and `CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT` as `0`. Why would this be the case when my localhost doesn't have any SSL certificates?

Comment: I don't understand how you could get https://example.com/ if you used localhost. Please, provide the script. 
Btw, I just saw your comment to the first post about automatic certificate updates when cloudflare SSL is enabled. You should keep in mind that communication chain looks like that: `[server1] -- https --> [cloudflare] --> plain http --> [server2]`

Comment: I first did the test on my 2 websites (as per my post). Then you had posted about how to verify the SSL result which also was gave a successful result. Then I decided to copy the **exact** code from `domain.com` onto my `localhost` to see if I could still get `example.com`'s contents without having SSL on my localhost. And I was able to. It also gave the same successful result using curl's SSL verification. I think I shouldn't have been able to get example.com's content from my localhost because it couldn't encrypt the ougoing request and decrypt the incoming data.

Comment: So to me, the chain looks like `[localhost] -- plain http --> [cloudflare] --> plain http -> [example.com] --> plain http --> [cloudflare] -- plain http --> [localhost]`

Comment: Why do you think your localhost's php dont have SSL support? libssl (openssl) is embeded into libcurl, and your script uses libcurl php bindings to make the request. 
I think you are not getting the idea of cloudflare right. It adds the encryption between clients and cloudflare servers proxying the client's request to your server.

Comment: `Why do you think your localhost's php dont have SSL support?` Because my localhost does not have HTTPS in front of its link. Its just `http://127.0.0.1/`. So to me, it doesn't encrypt the request. What certificate is it using to encrypt/decrypt? My understanding of SSL is: https://pastebin.com/Rev0Qr1Y

Comment: Your localhost script makes `outgoing` https request, there is no matter if you run it under http or https. I've looked through your pastebin note and yes, you misunderstand ssl and cloudflare concepts. We can discuss it in chat maybe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246139/discussion-between-leo-and-kiwa).